# highcharts dataLabels support RTL with enable hover it for show tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip, right-to-left

I use [`highcharts`](http://www.highcharts.com/), and need to `tooltip` and `dataLabels` in `pie` chart.
I have problem with `dataLabels` when in `RTL` direction.

I use this config:

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
             style: {
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontFamily: 'tahoma',
                direction: 'rtl',
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Result has a bug that you can see in this image:

[image]

See online: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/h4kv0t9v/

As research and suggest official site for `RTL` mode, I enabled `useHTML: true`:

[image]

Results OK, But data labels is not support mouse hover for show tooltip!

See online: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/h4kv0t9v/1/

And I try `useHTML: false` with remove `direction: rtl`:

[image]

As you see data label show in default `LTR` mode but is support mouse hover and clickable for show tooltips.

See online: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/h4kv0t9v/2/

Sure it's a bug of `highcharts` and I hope to resolve it by official site.

But now I need data label in `RTL` mode, and show default tooltip when hover it and also clickable for focus on related data series.
How can I resolve it?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a simple solution.

In this case, just use of a [`RLE` (Start of right-to-left embedding)](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-unicode-controls#basedirection) control character in text of `dataLabels`.

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        dataLabels: {
            format: '\u202B' + '{point.name}', // \u202B is RLE char for RTL support
```

But appears two bug in `IE9` and `EDGE` browsers. for resolve these, doing following solution.

Need this in title for `IE9` and `EDGE`:

```
title: {
    useHTML: true, //bug fixed `IE9` and `EDGE`
```

Need disable `textShadow` of `dataLabels` for `IE9` and `EDGE`:

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        dataLabels: {
            style: {
                textShadow: false, //bug fixed IE9 and EDGE
```

Completed code see in here online: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/h4kv0t9v/4/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add `onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` events for each label that will trigger show/hide of Highcharts tooltip. The code can be added in `dataLabel` format. Example (based on code from [your demo](https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/h4kv0t9v/1/)): https://jsfiddle.net/1czhyo92/

```
    format: '<span onmouseover="$(\'#container\').highcharts().tooltip.refresh($(\'#container\').highcharts().series[0].points[{point.x}])" onmouseleave="$(\'#container\').highcharts().tooltip.hide()">{point.name}</span>',
```

Comment: Thanks, But it's not be like default `tooltip`, in default, When you move the mouse, the `tooltip` also move and sticking to it. Other problem is with `z-index` of `tooltip`, and the `datalabel` is over on `tooltip`. Another problem is the `datalabel` is not clickable for focus on related `data series` and select that.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. HTML dataLabels doesn't have those features, you could add them yourself as shown with e.g. `mouseover` and `tooltip.refresh`. When using HTML dataLabels you should use HTML tooltip to make show over the HTML elements through setting higher `z-index` (CSS). Example of full-HTML tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/0wgy916n/